# Proof of Boole's inequality in two event case

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If we have the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$, how can we show that, for any $A, B \in \mathscr{F}$ we have: $$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) \leq \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)$$

Forgive me if I have missed another question asking this, but I haven't been able to find a resource that demonstrates this proof using measure/ probability theory axioms. It is a basic question but I struggle to understand how to approach it.

Comment: While you're in the area, it is worth going ahead and proving the stronger statement that $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$, the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  This is generally more useful of a fact and your statement follows trivially from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:
$$ \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) &\leq \mathbb{P}(A \cup B) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \\ &=
\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B \setminus A) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)\end{align*}$$
using that
$$A\cup B = A \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} (B\setminus A), \quad B = (B\setminus A)\mathbin{\dot{\cup}} (A\cap B)$$

Comment: Interesting use of $\dot{\cup}$.  I'm more familiar with seeing $\sqcup$ to represent disjoint union.  Out of curiosity, what region uses the $\dot{\cup}$ notation?

Comment: @JMoravitz don't know how common it exactly is; I just used this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/mathematical-symbol-for-disjoint-set-union But anyway I've seen both notations being used (Europe)

Answer (score 0):

$$A\cup B=(A-B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B-A)$$The sets on RHS are disjoint so that:$$P(A\cup B)=P(A-B)+P(A\cap B)+P(B-A)\leq P(A-B)+2P(A\cap B)+P(B-A)=$$$$P(A)+P(B)$$

Answer (score 0):

For any event $S$ let $$\chi_S=\begin{cases}1,&x\in S\\0,&x\notin S\end{cases}$$  so that $\Pr(S)=\int \chi_S$.  Note that $$\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_A+\chi_B-\chi_{A\cap B}$$